# Probability Mass Function Question with Constant C

Tags: probability

> The following are given:
>
> $X$ is a discrete random variable
>
> The probability mass function given is $P(X=k)=Clnk$
>
> $k=e$,$e^2$,$e^3$,$e^4$
>
> $C$ is a constant greater than zero
>
> We need to find the following
>
> 1. Constant, $C$
>
> 2. $E(lnX)$
>
> 3. $Var(lnX)$

For the constant I plugged in each value of k into the function and got for $k=e$, $Cln(e)=1C$, $k=e^2$, $Cln(e^2)=2C$ etc. up to the fourth power.  So this led me to $C+2C+3C+4C=1$ which gives us $C=\frac{1}{10}$

For the next part I am confused.  Even though the function includes the $C$ the expected value does not.  This same dilema occurs in the third question.  With these calculations is the C included or no cause even though the problem does not include the constant the function does.

Comment: The $C$ is in the probability mass function, so for example $E[\ln(X)]=\ln(e) P(X=e) + \ln(e^2) P(X=e^2) + \ln(e^3) P(X=e^3) + \ln(e^4) P(X=e^4)$, and those probabilities have the $C$ in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to see using $Y=lnX$.   This way $P(Y=m)=\frac{m}{10}$.  So $E(Y^n)=\frac{1}{10}\sum_{j=1}^4j^{n+1}$.  Result $E(Y)=3$, $E(Y^2)=10$ giving $var(Y)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have $\sum_{k=1}^4 \Pr(X=e^k)=1$; you correctly calculated the value of $C=\frac{1}{10}$.

The reason that the expected value does not include $C$, is because there is only 1 possible value that $C$ can be. If $C$ is not $\frac{1}{10}$, then the probabilities will not sum to $1$, which they must.

Once you already have $C$, you know the probability mass function is $\Pr(X = e^k) = \frac{1}{10} k$, with a support of $k\in {1, 2, 3, 4}$. From here, you just have to calculate the expected value in the usual way.
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{E}[X] &= \sum x\cdot \Pr(X=x) = \sum_{k=1}^4 e^k \cdot \frac{1}{10}k  \\
   &= \frac{1}{10}e + \frac{2}{10}e^2 + \frac{3}{10}e^3 + \frac{4}{10}e^4  \\
   &= \frac{e + 2e^2 + 3e^3 + 4e^4}{10} \\
   &\approx 29.6
\end{align}

You calculate the variance in the same way using the defnition of variance... I'll leave that to you. ;)